# Complex solutions to linear odes with real polynomial coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If a linear ODE with real polynomial coefficients, and a real independent variable has a complex solution, is it guaranteed that the complex conjugate of that solution is also a solution?

In other words, if $$f(t)+ig(t)$$ is a solution, can I conclude that $$f(t)$$ and $$g(t)$$ are also solutions?

In the case where the coefficients are *constant* it is my understanding that since the characteristic equation of such an ODE is a polynomial with real coefficients, then its complex roots must come in complex conjugate pairs. Therefore, complex solutions to the ODE must also come in complex conjugate pairs. Does this result extend to the case where the coefficients of the ODE are real polynomial?

Comment: If $L[y]=0$, then by arithmetic laws $\bar L[\bar y]=0$. By the reality of the linear operator $\bar L=L$, so that also $L[\bar y]=0$. Then conclude for real and imaginary part,... Which in the end puts in formulas what you already hinted at.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. Thank-you. It's simpler than I thought. Do you want to write this as an answer?